# How to open a window for a certain user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot that you can play games with by typing a command such as `!pong` and it will open a window to play the classic pong game. The problem is, whenever any user other than me types the command(such as `!snake`), it opens the window for me, not for them. How can i make the window open for them?
Here is my code:

```
    @client.command()
    async def snake(ctx):
      await ctx.send(f"Open snake game for {ctx.author.name}...")
      # Score
      score = 0
      high_score = 0

      # Set up the screen
      wn = turtle.Screen()
      wn.title("Snake Game")
      wn.bgcolor("green")
      wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
      wn.tracer(0) # Turns off the screen updates

      # Snake head
      head = turtle.Turtle()
      head.speed(0)
      head.shape("square")
      head.color("black")
      head.penup()
      head.goto(0,0)
      head.direction = "stop"

      # Snake food
      food = turtle.Turtle()
      food.speed(0)
      food.shape("circle")
      food.color("red")
      food.penup()
      food.goto(0,100)

      segments = []

      # Pen
      pen = turtle.Turtle()
      pen.speed(0)
      pen.shape("square")
      pen.color("white")
      pen.penup()
      pen.hideturtle()
      pen.goto(0, 260)
      pen.write("Score: 0  High Score: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

      # Functions
      def go_up():
          if head.direction != "down":
              head.direction = "up"

      def go_down():
          if head.direction != "up":
              head.direction = "down"

      def go_left():
          if head.direction != "right":
              head.direction = "left"

      def go_right():
          if head.direction != "left":
              head.direction = "right"

      def move():
          if head.direction == "up":
              y = head.ycor()
              head.sety(y + 20)

          if head.direction == "down":
              y = head.ycor()
              head.sety(y - 20)

          if head.direction == "left":
              x = head.xcor()
              head.setx(x - 20)

          if head.direction == "right":
              x = head.xcor()
              head.setx(x + 20)

      # Keyboard bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Check for a collision with the border
    if head.xcor()>290 or head.xcor()<-290 or head.ycor()>290 or head.ycor()<-290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0,0)
        head.direction = "stop"

        # Hide the segments
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        
        # Clear the segments list
        segments.clear()

        # Reset the score
        score = 0

        # Reset the delay
        delay = 0.1

        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score: {}  High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal")) 


    # Check for a collision with the food
    if head.distance(food) < 20:
        # Move the food to a random spot
        x = random.randint(-290, 290)
        y = random.randint(-290, 290)
        food.goto(x,y)

        # Add a segment
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("grey")
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)

        # Shorten the delay
        delay -= 0.001

        # Increase the score
        score += 10

        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score: {}  High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal")) 

    # Move the end segments first in reverse order
    for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x, y)

    # Move segment 0 to where the head is
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x,y)

    move()    

    # Check for head collision with the body segments
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0,0)
            head.direction = "stop"
        
            # Hide the segments
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        
            # Clear the segments list
            segments.clear()

            # Reset the score
            score = 0

            # Reset the delay
            delay = 0.1
        
            # Update the score display
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score: {}  High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()`
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I Think it's not possible to open a browser for other user.

Comment: You cannot. It's only opening for you because you're hosting it on your computer.

Comment: the program is running on your pc, so it can't be played by them

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have it open for them. You can only have it open for the person hosting the bot, if you would like this to work you would need them to download the bot themselves and run it. You could learn to make a browser-based game(will require knowledge of HTML/CSS/js) and generate a new link so they can play on their own browser.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are waiting for key presses here:

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")
```

While you should be waiting for messages using bot.wait_for(). You can read the official documentation for more information.